# PayPal roundtrip sandbox testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am looking for a way for the PayPal sandbox for a round trip test:

1. create a payment and redirect the user to PayPal so he can log in and approve
2. user follow the redirect and log in and approve the payment
3. verify payment on shop side

The steps 1. and 3. are not the problem. But how can I approve the payment automatically in the sand box. IMHO this is a scenario which every developer should need for automatic regression testing but I could not find any solution.

I use Java JUnit for regression tests.

I have tried with WebClient, but PayPal nags about cookies and JavaScript. So I got no success with that.

Comment: Have you tried Selenium or Webtest?

Comment: Well, Selenium needs UI. But you hint to Webtest brings me to new ideas with WebClient. So, thx for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I could log in into PayPal developer page. Maybe for someone else this is useful.

`package paypaltest;`

import java.io.IOException;

public class htmlUnitTest extends TestCase {

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);
    wc.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    wc.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    wc.setWebConnection(new TestHttpWebConnection(wc));
    try {
        final HtmlPage page = wc.getPage("https://developer.paypal.com/");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
        final List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlAnchor loginAnchor = null;
        for (final HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor : anchors) {
            if (htmlAnchor.getHrefAttribute().startsWith("https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize?client_id")) {
                loginAnchor = htmlAnchor;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (loginAnchor != null) {
            System.out.println("### login anchor");
            System.out.println(loginAnchor.asXml());
            System.out.println("### login to: " + loginAnchor.getHrefAttribute());
            final HtmlPage loginPage = wc.getPage(loginAnchor.getHrefAttribute());
            System.out.println("### login page");
            System.out.println(loginPage.asXml());
            final HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getForms().get(0);
            final HtmlInput email = loginForm.getInputByName("email");
            final HtmlInput password = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
            final HtmlInput login = loginForm.getInputByValue("Log In");
            email.setValueAttribute("my@email.com");
            password.setValueAttribute("password");
            final HtmlPage loggedInPage = login.click();
            System.out.println("### logged in page");
            System.out.println(loggedInPage.asXml());

        }
        final HtmlPage pageLoggedIn = wc.getPage("https://developer.paypal.com/");
        System.out.println("### page logged in ");
        System.out.println(pageLoggedIn.asXml());

    } catch (final FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static final class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SchemeLayeredSocketFactory {

    // ** Log object for this class. *//*
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(EasySSLSocketFactory.class);

    private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

    public Socket createSocket(final HttpParams params) throws IOException {
        final SSLSocket sock = (SSLSocket) getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        return sock;
    }

    public Socket createLayeredSocket(final Socket socket, final String target, final int port, final HttpParams params) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
        final SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, target, port, true);
        // verifyHostName() didn't blowup - good!
        return sslSocket;
    }

    public Socket connectSocket(final Socket socket, final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, final InetSocketAddress localAddress, final HttpParams params)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {

        if (remoteAddress == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Remote address may not be null");
        if (params == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP parameters may not be null");
        final Socket sock = socket != null ? socket : getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        if (localAddress != null) {
            sock.setReuseAddress(HttpConnectionParams.getSoReuseaddr(params));
            sock.bind(localAddress);
        }

        final int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        final int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

        try {
            sock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
            sock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
        } catch (final SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            throw new ConnectTimeoutException("Connect to " + remoteAddress + " timed out");
        }

        String hostname;
        if (remoteAddress instanceof HttpInetSocketAddress) {
            hostname = ((HttpInetSocketAddress) remoteAddress).getHttpHost().getHostName();
        } else {
            hostname = remoteAddress.getHostName();
        }

        SSLSocket sslsock;
        // Setup SSL layering if necessary
        if (sock instanceof SSLSocket) {
            sslsock = (SSLSocket) sock;
        } else {
            final int port = remoteAddress.getPort();
            sslsock = (SSLSocket) getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(sock, hostname, port, true);
        }
        return sslsock;
    }

    public boolean isSecure(final Socket sock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (sock == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Socket may not be null");
        // This instanceof check is in line with createSocket() above.
        if (!(sock instanceof SSLSocket))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Socket not created by this factory");
        // This check is performed last since it calls the argument object.
        if (sock.isClosed())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Socket is closed");
        return true;
    }

    private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() {
        try {
            final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
            return context;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new HttpClientError(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() {
        if (this.sslcontext == null) {
            this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
        }
        return this.sslcontext;
    }

}

public static final class TestHttpWebConnection extends HttpWebConnection {

    public TestHttpWebConnection(final WebClient webClient) {
        super(webClient);

        final SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = getHttpClient().getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry();
        final SchemeSocketFactory socketFactory = new EasySSLSocketFactory();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory));
    }
}
```

}